# Retrieve & Update functions for summing two arrays in a third one

Tags: arrays, c, sum, 2d

I am new in c programmaing and I need your help. I have a project in which I am given three arrays A, B, C with pointer value 1..10. I want to a create a C program using the retrieve and update functions, in order to implement the sum of the arrays A:= B + C.

My code so far,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];

    for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
      printf("Type a number for v1 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v1[i]);

      printf("Type a number for v2 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
      // Add here
      v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
  }

  printf("\nResult Arr :\n");
  for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", v3[i]);
}
```

But I seem that I totally miss the retrieve and update functions. According to my notes the retrieve function is equal to retrieve(S, c, i). The variable c get provided the value of component S which corresponds to the value of pointer i. The update(S, c, i) provides the value of variable c to the component of the array S which corresponds to the value of pointer i.

Any ideas on how to pproach this???

Answer (score 1):

you should try both `retrieve` and `update` methods first, I'm pretty sure that is your homework and not the code you sent... Anyways, my approach would be, if I understand your homework correctly, that the `c` in the `retrieve` function has to be a pointer to set the value of `array[i]` and the `c` in the `update` has to be a value. I'm showing how I would make the retrieve one, and how to call it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int retrieve (int * array, int  *c, int i){
    if (array[i]==NULL){
        printf("i is out of range");
        return -1; // You could also return max integer for error purposes
    }
    *c = array[i];
    return 0; // Returned with no errors
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];

    for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
      printf("Type a number for v1 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v1[i]);

      printf("Type a number for v2 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
      // Add here
      v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
  }
  int c=1;
  retrieve(v1,&c,0);
  printf("%d",c);
  printf("\nResult Arr :\n");
  for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
    printf("%d\n", v3[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for efforts. Didn't mean to provoke any offense. As I told at the beginning of my question, I am new to C and I am trying different implementations. If that's a big deal, I will try to be more cautious next time I am making any question. But I am also pretty sure that no one was born with knowledge on c. Everyone must start from somewhere. Anyway, thank you again and I will try the update one.